# I can't use step counter sensor

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sensors

I'm try to make basic step counter app, but i have a issue. Here is my code. Just else brackets working. Where is the problem? Thank you for your all helping.

**Here is my code;**

```
  sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

        if (sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER) != null) {
            mStepCounter = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
            isCounterSensorPresent = true;
            tv_stepCounter.setText("counter sensor");
        } else {
            tv_stepCounter.setText("counter sensor is not present");
            isCounterSensorPresent = false;
        }
```

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER) != null) {
            sensorManager.registerListener(this, mStepCounter, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER) != null) {
            sensorManager.unregisterListener(this, mStepCounter);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        if (sensorEvent.sensor == mStepCounter) {
            stepCount = (int) sensorEvent.values[0];
            tv_stepCounter.setText(String.valueOf(stepCount));
        }

    }
```

**And here is my permissions.**

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            //ask for permission
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION}, 0);
        }
```

**And**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />
```

Comment: `Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER` isn't available on all devices.

Comment: I was using sHealth on my phone. I thought they could have done the pedometer this way. All aside can't i simulate this with using emulator ? @MarkusKauppinen